# Analog input pins protection

Tags: voltage, diodes, circuit-protection

Several times I have seen schematics with a BAT54S, 2 diodes connected in series. The purpose is to protect over or under voltage but i can't fully understand how it works.

For example with an I/O or analog pin of a microcontroller:

[image]

Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: This circuit **can** protect but up to a point. If I connect -5 V to External I/O from a supply which can deliver 10 A, the bottom BAT54S will smoke. The MCU will be safe though since it also has  (ESD protection) diodes to supply and ground and that 100 ohm limits the current. So add a 100 ohms also in series with External IO and this protection will be even better.

Comment: @Andyaka Something familiar, something peculiar, something for everyone....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you make believe, for the moment, that those are ideal diodes, both diodes are "off" when Vin is in the range 0-VDD.  When Vin fall below zero, the bottom diode is on, effectively shorting the input to zero, and when Vin is above VDD, the top diode is on, effectively clamping the input at VDD.

Comment: Thank you for the answers and sorry by the forum mistake. Best regards

Answer (score 1):

These diodes also add capacitance and leakage current.

And the diodes will couple trash, from GND and from VDD, onto the analog pin.

Comment: That's all true, but doesn't address the question.

Comment: diode leakage current can be a nuisance if coupled with high resistances and can give false readings. It is something to be aware of